# ng-repeat issue in angular js,$scope binding with the view

Tags: angularjs, http

`ng-repeat` is not binding with the `$scope` as the `data-set` is being generated in the console.
Here is the working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/qFbt43ZzmtChDcWeHlGv?p=preview)

Kindly load it over *http* as the data set may not be generated over *https*.

Any workaround would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a costly but silly miss; the injection order went wrong in your main controller which resulted in injecting `$scope` to `$timeout` alias and vice versa. Change

```
.controller('demoController',['$mdDialog','$q','$scope','$timeout','$http',
function($mdDialog,$q,$timeout,$scope,$http) {
```

to

```
.controller('demoController', ['$mdDialog', '$q', '$scope', '$timeout', '$http',
function($mdDialog, $q, $scope, $timeout, $http) {
```

Comment: Hahaha. I just ignored that part unfortunately :(

Comment: Thanks .Helped me a lot!